# Set a maximum number value for a text field

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

I'm making an app where students enter their grade in a specific text field. I want them to enter a number from 0 to 100. I was just wondering how do we set a maximum NUMBER value for a textfield.

I'm assuming I'm supposed to make some type of action but I'm not sure what action type to use or the code to set a maximum value.

Any help would be very appreciated :) !!

Comment: You could use a UIPickerView with values from 0 to 100.

Comment: @vacawama I would but I'm new to swift and xcode and I really don't know how to use UIPickerView

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIPickerView if you want to present a limited number of fixed answers: http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/. But if you want to have them enter it in a textbox, you can validate the input in the textFieldDidEndEditing method like so:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
   if textField.text.toInt() < 0 || textfield.text.toInt() > 100 {
      //Here you can present an alert, change the input or clear the field.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make the score 0 when negative and 100 when the user enters something more than 100. This allows you to enter fractional score like 72.5:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Make sure the user entered a number
        guard let score = Double(textField.text!) else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Score", message: "Score must be a number from 0 to 100", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }

        if score < 0 {
            textField.text = "0"
        } else if score > 100 {
            textField.text = "100"
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {



    if ((self.inputTextField?.text)!.characters.count > 10 && range.length == 0)

    {
        return false
        //return false // return NO to not change text
    }else{

        return true

    }

}
```

Note: Import text field UITextFieldDelegat.